# ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL in IDENTITY COLUMN

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I am using Oracle 12c, and I generated a table with an identity primary key:

```
 create table t
    ( x int
        generated as identity
            primary key,
      y varchar2(30)
    )
```

When I run an `insert` statement like this:

```
insert into t (y) 
 select 'a' from dual
```

everything looks fine. But when I want to use a `union` in the `select` statement it gives an error:

```
insert into t (y) 
 select 'a' from dual
 union
 select 'b' from dual
```

Error report:

> SQL Error: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("REPORT"."T"."X")
>   01400. 00000 -  "cannot insert NULL into (%s)"
>   *Cause:    An attempt was made to insert NULL into previously listed objects.
>   *Action:   These objects cannot accept NULL values.

Comment: I don't have Oracle 12c, but you might try:
`insert into t (y) 
select from (
select 'a' from dual
union
select 'b' from dual)`
It's just a shot in the dark...

Comment: There are some options to how Identity columns are created. I don't have a 12c in my dev environment at the moment, but try to create the column  x int GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY primary key.

Comment: Extra strange: Oracle 12c, without an `ALWAYS` or `BY DEFAULT` option it defaults to [`ALWAYS`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CJAHJHJC).  I can't think of a good reason why the first insert works but the second doesn't.